# Как правильно записать функцию по отправке сообщения пользователю? TeleBot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, schedule

Вот код, нужно что-бы по команде `schedule.every().day.at("10:27").do(send_messange)` бот посылал сообщение пользователю вот пример

```
def send_messange(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы где-то будете хранить значение id чата (переменная, база данных, и т.п.), поэтому в функцию `send_message` лучше передавать его, а не объект сообщения

В `<CHAT_ID>` передавайте реальное значение

```
...
def send_message(chat_id: int, text: str):
    bot.send_message(chat_id, text)

schedule.every().day.at("10:27").do(send_message, chat_id=<CHAT_ID>, text="Text")
...
```